# Uniform convergence and uniform boundedness

Tags: real-analysis

I try to understand a demonstration from a book, but I have a problem with a line.
We have the series
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{g^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k} \qquad (*)$$
where
$$g(t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
        \exp\left(-\frac{1}{t^2}\right) & \mbox{if } t > 0 \\
        0 & \mbox{if } t \leq 0
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
and we try to prove that it's well defined for $x$ and $t$ real, that we can take the derivatives, and so on. We have already proved that when $t > 0$,
$$\left|\frac{g^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right| \leq \frac{|x|^{2k}}{k!(\theta t)^k}\exp\left[-\frac{1}{2t^2}\right]$$
for some $\theta > 0$. We then have directly
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \left|\frac{g^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right| \leq \exp\left[\frac{|x|^2}{\theta t} - \frac{1}{2t^2}\right]$$
So they say that, by comparison, our series $(*)$ converges and that $\lim_{t\rightarrow 0}u(x,t) = 0$, I agree on that.

Here is the point I don't understand. It's said :

"The series $(*)$ as a power series in $x$ is majorised (they say that $f$ is majorised by $F$ if the derivatives of $f$ in $0$ are less than the corresponding derivatives of $F$ in $0$) by the power series for
$$U(x,t) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
        \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{\theta t} - \frac{1}{2t^2}\right) & \mbox{if } t > 0 \\
        0 & \mbox{if } t \leq 0
    \end{array}
\right.$$
Since $U(x,t)$ is bounded uniformly for bounded complex $x$ and all real $t$, the series $(*)$ converges uniformly in $(x,t)$ for bounded $x$ and real $t$, and the same holds for the series obtained by the term by term $x$-differentiations."

I actually don't understand what they mean when they say that $U(x,t)$ is bounded uniformly. Do they mean that the power series of $U$ is uniformly bounded? But which series? The one with respect to $x$ ? And even with that, I don't understand how we can conclude that $(*)$ converges uniformly...

Don't hesitate to ask if something is unclear in what I said!

I hope you could help me,

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 3):

I believe a uniform bound on $U$ simply means there exists $C > 0$ such that for all $x \in (-1,1),~t \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $|U(x,t)| < C$ (in vector space terminology, its supremum-norm is finite).

Can you see why this implies the convergence of the power series?

---

EDIT: Okay, so let $B\subset\mathbb{C}$ be bounded, consider the domain $D:=B\times\mathbb{R}$. You want to show that for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n>N$:
\begin{equation}\sup\limits_{(x,t)\in D}|u(x,t)-u_n(x,t)|<\varepsilon.\end{equation}
We know that for any $(x,t)\in D$,
\begin{align}
|u(x,t) - u_n(x,t)| &= \left|\sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \frac{g^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right| \\
&\leq \sum\limits_{k=n}^\infty \left|\frac{g^{(k)}(t)}{(2k)!}x^{2k}\right|
\end{align}
Can you take it from there?

Comment: That's a possibility... I find it weird to say "uniform" since a bound is always uniform (saying that $U(x,t)$ is bounded for some $(x,t)$ is not very interesting).
Actually, if we prove that the series of U converges uniformly, we are done.
Is it true that a series which converges and whose limit is bounded necessarily converges uniformly?

Comment: No that's not true... :(

Comment: Yes I know what uniform and pointwise convergences are. Here the series $(*)$ converges (pointwise convergence), but I can't understand why the convergence is uniform. It is "majorised" by a sequence whose limit is bounded, I don't see why this implies that we have a uniform convergence...

Comment: I found the "uniform" weird because, for me, saying that the function was bounded for $x$ bounded and $t$ real wound have been enough (a bound on a certain space is always uniform, we never talk about a bound which is not uniform!)

Comment: Yes but how this $\sup\limits_{\substack{x \in [-1,1] \\ t \in \mathbb{R}}} | u(x,t) - u_n(x,t) | \rightarrow 0$ can be proved? It's supposed to be in the sentence "Since $U(x,t)$ is bounded uniformly for bounded complex $x$ and all real $t$, the series $(∗)$ converges uniformly in $(x,t)$ for bounded $x$ and real $t$"

Comment: Sorry but you don't really help me... I've already searched for hours and your hints which are just reformulation of the definition of uniform convergence don't help me a lot. I've succeeded to prove the uniform convergence on every compact, using the boundedness of $U$, I'll do with that. Thank you for your time ;)

Comment: Well I am sorry I couldn't help, I must admit a little more work on it and I'm fairly stumped. Could you explain more clearly what you mean by "The series (∗) as a power series in $x$ is majorised (they say that $f$ is majorised by $F$ if the derivatives of $f$ in $0$ are less than the corresponding derivatives of $F$ in $0$) by the power series for..."? Specifically, what is a derivative of $f$ in $0$? $f^{(k)}(0)$?

Comment: Actually, they say "... is majorised (see p.67) ...", and the definition of majorised is precisely, page 67 :

"Let $f$, $F$ be functions with domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and range in $\mathbb{R}^m$, of class $C^\infty$ in a neighborhood of the origin. We say $f$ is majorised by $F$, if 

$|D^\alpha f_k(0)| \leq D^\alpha F_k(0)$ for all $\alpha \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ and all $k$."

I suppose that what they mean here is that each term of the series $(*)$ is less than the corresponding term of the series of $U$. We have proved it, as I've just added in my first post.